# Searchable dropdown menu with async data in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, searchable-dropdown

I'm trying to use a searchable dropdown menu in expo with async storage but when I try to write a text I get "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'item.name.toLowerCase')". I need help please, I would appreciate it a lot.

Also, the dropdown menu remains blank but when I click on it alerts the data. I don't know what else to do.

```
    try {
      const keys = await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys();
      const items = await AsyncStorage.multiGet(keys);
      setItem(items);
    } catch (error) {
      alert(error);
    }
  };
```

````
<SearchableDropdown
        onTextChange={(text) => console.log(text)}
        //On text change listner on the searchable input
        onItemSelect={(item) => alert(JSON.stringify(item))}
        //onItemSelect called after the selection from the dropdown
        containerStyle={{ padding: 5 }}
        //suggestion container style
        textInputStyle={{
          //inserted text style
          padding: 12,
          borderWidth: 1,
          borderColor: "#ccc",
          backgroundColor: "#FAF7F6",
        }}
        itemStyle={{
          //single dropdown item style
          padding: 10,
          marginTop: 2,
          backgroundColor: "#FAF9F8",
          borderColor: "#bbb",
          borderWidth: 1,
        }}
        itemTextStyle={{
          //text style of a single dropdown item
          color: "#222",
        }}
        itemsContainerStyle={{
          //items container style you can pass maxHeight
          //to restrict the items dropdown hieght
          maxHeight: "60%",
        }}
        items={item}
        //mapping of item array
        defaultIndex={2}
        //default selected item index
        placeholder="placeholder"
        //place holder for the search input
        resetValue={false}
        //reset textInput Value with true and false state
        underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
        //To remove the underline from the android input
      />```
````

Answer (score 0):

In case you're using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-searchable-dropdown , Refactor this line

```
<SearchableDropdown
 
        // You wrote item instead items
        items={items}
        the underline from the android input
      />
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. Its item because I set the item in the code above